# Laravel upload to cpanel css issue

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to upload a laravel project to cpanel hosting server. My laravel version is 5.3 and php version on the server is 5.6.

What I have done is:

1. Create a folder called "online_system" to root of file manager.
2. Copy contents of laravel project except public folder.
3. Create a folder called "online_system" to public_html.
4. Copy contents of public folder of laravel project.
5. Jump to index.php file.
6. Edit `require __DIR__.'/../../online_system/bootstrap/autoload.php';`
7. Edit `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../online_system/bootstrap/app.php';`
8. Change .env to link DB.
9. Open domain/online_system.

[image]

**Home page is working fine**, but as long as I click login or register provided by laravel, then the website looks plain without css load.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: could you please expand `online_system` directory inthe picture and share layout link to css file.

Comment: @MortezaRajabi Hi, unfortunately I cannot access it right now until I am home. But there is nothing, just the contents of public folder as I described here. I will do it later. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{{ url('online_system/css/styl.css') }}" />
```

Comment: I tried it at resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php as this is the layouts that all my views are using, but still have the same problem???

Comment: @brianLikeApple In your browser, `View Page Source` and check the `href="..."`

Comment: That is what I am saying, all my views are using one specific layout, so href will be from layout code. I tried it, it is not working at all. Have you done any similar things before? Is it working?

Comment: Yes. Currently, I'm managing a multi-tenant Laravel application on cPanel. It's ok.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to give the correct path for css. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will do the trick:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/public/css/style.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project is on the server and change your views, So clear view cache:

```
php /path_to_your_project/ artisan view:clear
```